# Does Apache really "fork" in mod_php/python way for request handling?

Tags: apache, webserver, cgi, mod-python, mod-php

I am a dummy in web apps. I have a doubt regaring the functioning of apache web server. My question is mainly centered on "how apache handles each incoming request"

**Q:** When apache is running in the `mod_python`/`mod_php` mode, then does a "fork" happen for each incoming reuest?

- If it forks in `mod_php`/`mod_python` way, then where is the advantage over CGI mode, except for the fact that the forked process in `mod_php` way already contains an interpretor instance.
- If it doesn't fork  each time, how does it actually handle each incoming request in the `mod_php`/`mod_python` way. Does it use threads?

**PS:** Where does FastCGI stands in the above comparison?

Answer (score 0):

With a modern version of Apache, unless you configure it in `prefork` mode, it should run threaded (and not fork). `mod_python` is threadsafe, and doesn't require that each instance of it is forked into its own space.